# Calling execvp two times causes second execvp to use first execvp's arguments

Tags: c++, shell

I have a really strange bug and I don't know why this is happening, I'm trying to create a shell and if I want to call in multiple execvp's it does not work. It works if I just pass in echo hello, but if I have echo hello for the first execvp and echo hello world for the second execvp, the second execvp will print "hello echo hello world".

```
    void testexecute(char** arglist){
    int k;
    int status=0;
    pid_t child_pid;
    child_pid=fork();
    cout<<"This is our child_pid number "<<child_pid<<endl;
        if (child_pid == -1){
            // error, failed to fork()
        }
        else if (child_pid > 0){
            int status;
            waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);
            cout<<"Our status here be "<<status<<endl;
            return status;
        }
        else {
            // we are the child
            if(execvp(arglist[0],arglist)==-1)
            {
                    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);   // exec never returns
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"Second else has reached "<<endl;
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
int main() { 
    char *argv[] = {"echo","testing","these","functions"};
    char *argvlist2[]= {"echo"," testssss","1","2"};
    testexecute(argvlist2);
    testexecute(argv);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code this is my output

```
testssss 1 2
testing these functions echo  testssss 1 2
```

I tried checking the contents of the arguments inside testexecute and it passes in the correct argument, so I don't know why it is also passing in the previous argument into execvp().

Comment: The argument lists must be terminated by a sentinel `NULL` at the end of each... E.g. `char *argv[] = {"echo","testing","these","functions", NULL};`

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed my problem.

Comment: You are welcome. Always code with your editor and the [execvp(3) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) open in the browser `:)`